# Can't name a file containing special characters

Tags: python, filenames

I want to name a file containing special characters, but I get an error when I try to do so

```
with open('My filename: one | two.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write('something')
```

and get this error :

`OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'My filename: one | two.txt'`

How can I name a file containing special characters?

Comment: Are you on a windows machine? You can't.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the OS, but for Microsoft, these are the specific characters not allowed in filenames and vertical bar (|) is one of them.

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file:

> Use any character in the current code page for a name, including
> Unicode characters and characters in the extended character set
> (128–255), except for the following:
>
> - The following reserved characters:
>
>   - < (less than)
>   - > (greater than)
>   - : (colon)
>   - " (double quote)
>   - / (forward slash)
>   - \ (backslash)
>   - | (vertical bar or pipe)
>   - ? (question mark)
>   - * (asterisk) Integer value zero, sometimes referred to as the ASCII NUL character.
> - Characters whose integer representations are in the range from 1
>   through 31, except for alternate data streams where these characters
>   are allowed. For more information about file streams, see File
>   Streams.
> - Any other character that the target file system does not allow.